# why don't I get the DateTime value of the X Axis

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graph, charts, tooltip

When I run the code for every point I find that the x-Value is 0.0

I dont know how to fix it; I tried to convert it to pixels and then to value but same result. the graph contains a price for every date.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)//making the anual graph
 {
                annual.Series["close"].Points.AddXY((DateTime.ParseExact(a[i].Date, "yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")), a[i].close);
 }



 Point? prevPosition = null;
      private void annual_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
         {
             var pos = e.Location;
             if (prevPosition.HasValue && pos == prevPosition.Value)
                 return;
             toolTip1.RemoveAll();
             prevPosition = pos;
             var results = annual.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false,
                                             ChartElementType.DataPoint);
             var results1 = candlestickchart.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false,
                                             ChartElementType.DataPoint);
             foreach (var result in results)
             {
                 if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)// check if it is a point on the graph
                 {         
                     var prop = result.Object as DataPoint;// look on the result as a point
                     if (prop != null)
                     {
                         var pointYPixel = result.ChartArea.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(prop.YValues[0]);

                         // check if the cursor is really close to the point (3 pixels around)
                         if (Math.Abs(pos.Y - pointYPixel) < 3)
                         {
                             toolTip1.Show("PRICE=" + prop.YValues[0].ToString("0.00")+'$', this.annual,pos.X, pos.Y - 15);
                             label3.Text = prop.XValue.ToString();<========
                             label4.Text = prop.YValues[0].ToString("0.00") + '$';                              
                         }
                         }
                     }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this line:

```
annual.Series["close"].Points.AddXY((DateTime.ParseExact(a[i].Date,
                      "yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")), a[i].close);
```

The `ParseExact` method returns `DateTime` which would be fine, but then you re-format it back to string again!

**X-Values always contain double**, either coming from numbers or from `DateTime` values converted automatically via the [DateTime.ToOADate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.100).aspx) method. If you add the X-Values as strings they are all set to zero, because those strings are **neither numbers nor DataTimes**.

This is **easy to miss**, as the automatic `Labels` are in fact set to the very strings, so everything **looks** fine.

But the problems come up as soon as you try to **do** anything with those X-Values..like calculations, setting an `Interval`, formatting, displaying `ToolTips` or `CustomLabels` etc etc..

To add the X-values as `DateTimes` change the line to

```
annual.Series["close"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.ParseExact(a[i].Date,
                      "yyyyMMdd", null), a[i].close);
```

and set the `Format` for the `Labels`:

```
yourChartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478763/is-it-possible-to-match-two-series-of-data-in-a-chart-from-two-different-dataset/31483413?s=7|0.7025#31483413) for an extended discussion!

### So: Always try to add the X-Values as numbers or dates, never as strings!